# AutoHotKey: How can I send CTRL B in my code Along with other text in bracket

Tags: automation, autohotkey

Here is my autohotkey code:

```
::\update client::
(
Hi team,

We are emailing to advise you an update on following job:
#CTRL-B Here
Here
•   Our Reference:
Your Reference:
#CTRL-B Here
)
```

I am trying to replace word update client with a paragraph of text. I want to send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> key before bullet points and after bullet points. How can I do it? Can someone please help me with syntax? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need  to divide the text.

```
::\update client::
SendInput
(
Hi team,

We are emailing to advise you an update on following job:
)
SendInput, ^b
SendInput
(
Here
•   Our Reference:
Your Reference:
)
SendInput, ^b
Return
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution using the new line character.

```
::test::
    SendInput Hi team,`n`nWe are emailing to advise you an update on following job:
    SendInput ^b
    SendInput Here`n•   Our Reference:`nYour Reference:
    SendInput ^b
    return
```